# jcabi ssh redirect output to null or file

Tags: java, ssh, jcabi

I'm writing a small application to connect to a list of servers through SSH and execute a few commands.  I'm using [jcabi-ssh](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-ssh).  When I run the program, jcabi-ssh outputs to the console with lines such as:

```
[main] WARN com.jcabi.ssh.SSH - Permanently added '192.168.4.2' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
[main] INFO com.jcabi.ssh.Execution$Default - $ ping -c 1 google.com
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
Shell shell = new SSHByPassword(targetServer.toString(), Integer.parseInt(port), username.toString(), password.toString());
exitCode=shell.exec("ping -c 1 google.com",stdin,stdout,stderr);
```

I would like to either hide the console output or redirect it to a file.  I looked through the [source](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-ssh/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcabi/ssh/Shell.java) but it seems like I can't do it through the method call.  Is there a way to do what I wanted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just suppress logging in your application. jcabi-ssh is using slf4j. What you see in logs is coming through slf4j to (most probably) log4j. Make sure log level from `com.jcabi.ssh` is set to `ERROR` and you will be fine.